# JSON_MODIFY does not work with variable parameter

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2019

I have a SQL query which modifies some JSON. I'm iterating through the data and modifies part of the JSON based on the iteration.

For that i need to pass a variable parameter into JSON_MODIFY, but for some reason, it doesn't work!

```
SET @json = JSON_MODIFY(@ProData, '$.' + @ProKey + '.hasAnswer', CAST(1 as BIT))
```

**I also tried passing the whole expression as a variable:**

```
DECLARE @hasAnswerPath VARCHAR(100);
SET @hasAnswerPath = '$.' + @ProKey + '.hasAnswer';
SET @json = JSON_MODIFY(@ProData, @hasAnswerPath, CAST(1 as BIT))
```

But it has the same output, the hasAnswer is added to the root of the JSON and not in the element specified by @ProKey.

**This works just fine:**

```
SET @json = JSON_MODIFY(@ProData, '$.SomeName1.hasAnswer', CAST(1 as BIT))
```

It's like the @ProKey is disregarded.

**Complete query:**

```
BEGIN TRAN

DECLARE @ProID as uniqueidentifier;
DECLARE @ProData as nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @ProKey as varchar(200);

DECLARE ProCursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT Id, [Data] FROM [dbo].[PRO]

OPEN ProCursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM ProCursor INTO @ProID, @ProData;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(max);

    DECLARE DataCursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT [key] FROM OPENJSON(@ProData) WHERE type = 5; --5 is object data
        
    OPEN DataCursor;
    FETCH NEXT FROM DataCursor INTO @ProKey;
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @json=JSON_MODIFY(@ProData, '$.' + @ProKey + '.hasAnswer', CAST(1 as BIT))
        SET @json=JSON_MODIFY(@json,'$.' + @ProKey + '.questionType','intro')
        
        FETCH NEXT FROM DataCursor INTO @ProKey;
    END;

    UPDATE [dbo].[PRO]
    SET [Data] = @json
    WHERE Id = @ProID

    PRINT @json

    CLOSE DataCursor;
    DEALLOCATE DataCursor;

    FETCH NEXT FROM ProCursor INTO @ProID, @ProData;
END
CLOSE ProCursor;
DEALLOCATE ProCursor;

ROLLBACK
```

**Sample JSON:**

```
 {
     "SomeName1": {
        "header": "Some text",
        "answer": {
            "type": "specified",
            "numberValue": 1.0
        }
     },
     "SomeName2": {
        "header": "Some text",
        "answer": {
            "type": "specified",
            "numberValue": 4.0
         }
     },
     "SomeName3": {
         "header": "Some text",
         "answer": {
             "type": "specified",
             "numberValue": 2.0
        }
     }
 }
```

**Expected result:**

```
},
    "SomeName1": {
        "header": "Some text",
        "answer": {
            "type": "specified",
            "numberValue": 1.0
        }
        "hasAnswer": true,
        "questionType": "intro",
     }
}
```

**Actual result:**

```
},
    "SomeName1": {
            "header": "Some text",
            "answer": {
                "type": "specified",
                "numberValue": 1.0
            }
         }
     },
     "hasAnswer":true,
     "questionType":"intro"
 }
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Perhaps something is wrong with the code that you didn't post. Is there anything useful that you could add? Like what the json looks like and the unexpected result?

Comment: It can easily be tested with creating a new table with columns Id and Data and insert NewGuid and JSON sample

Comment: Please have one more look at the actual result. Is the last key populated correctly (and other ones aren't)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be overwriting your variables unintentionally:

```
-- first iteration

SET @json=JSON_MODIFY(@ProData, '$.' + @ProKey + '.hasAnswer', CAST(1 as BIT))
-- @json contains the @prodata after modification to first key (@prodata itself is not changed)

SET @json=JSON_MODIFY(@json,'$.' + @ProKey + '.questionType','intro')
-- @json (its first key to be more precise) is modified further
```

But on next iteration, this line will revert the modified `@json` back to the original value of `@prodata`. Only the last key will retain the modifications:

```
-- second iteration

SET @json=JSON_MODIFY(@ProData, '$.' + @ProKey + '.hasAnswer', CAST(1 as BIT))
-- you just overwrote your modifications with the value inside @prodata
```

The solution is to re-arrange the code a little, may be initialize `@json` outside the loop.

Comment: But the problem is not json or ProData, but that ProKey is not working as a parameter in JSON_MODIFY.

Comment: I have no clue then. There is an obvious flaw in your code, it'll only update the last key. There is no way for it to update the parent. `$..foo` or `null` should throw an exception instead of modifying root object. May be your JSON is nested two lavels deep which you did not post.